# CodeIgniter router doesn't work on a specific server

Tags: codeigniter, routes

I am developing a single page web site so all routes should lead to the default router. This is how I've achieved that through the routes.php file:

```
$route['default_controller'] = "home";
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['admin'] = 'admin/home'; 
$route['^/'] = "home";

$route['(.*)'] = $route['default_controller'];
```

Thats working as expected on a test server and on the local host, but on  the actuall server, when I try to find any of the pages I am getting the 404 error. Any ideas what could be wrong?

Comment: You seem to have asked a similar question earlier.  Please consider rewriting these two questions as one and delete the one that is redundant.  Thank you.

Comment: Is this a different question to your last one?

Answer (score 0):

```
$route['default_controller'] = "home";
$route['404_override'] = "home/index";   
$route['.*'] = "home/index/$1"
```